# unbuffered std streambuf implementation

Tags: c++, sockets, iostream

for some quick testing of a serialization library I want to create a streambuf that can read/write to/from a socket. I do not want to use a buffer in the streambuf, but let the socket handle this. I am sure the serialization lib will only call `std::istream::read` and `std::ostream::write`. A quick look at Microsoft's basic_streambuf implementation shows that these calls are practically directly forwarded to `xsputn` and `xsgetn`.

The question is: can I derive from a streambuf and just implement xsputn and xsgetn, and be sure that the streams that use my implementation will always call these methods, and not sync/overflow/underflow/pback/... ? Or else should I override sync etc to return errors, or does the standard guarantee that the default implementations are fine? Preferrably this should work on any common platform, and I cannot use the boost::iostreams.

Practically I'd use something like this:

```
class socket_buf : public std::streambuf
{
public:
    //Socket is a class with std::stream-like read/write methods
  MyBuf( Socket& s ) : sock( s ) {}

protected:
  std::streamsize xsputn( const char* s, std::streamsize n )
  {
    return sock.write( s, n );
  }

  std::streamsize xsgetn( char* s, std::streamsize n )
  {
    return sock.read( s, n );
  }

private:
  Socket& sock;
};
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's (almost?) impossible to implement a `std::streambuf` without a buffer. You will have to overload `underflow` and `overflow` as many of the public interfaces to `std::streambuf` won't go via `xsputn` or `xsgetn`. E.g. `sputc`, `sbumpc`, etc. Even `sputn` is not guaranteed to cause a call `xsputn` depending on the state of the internal buffer and the particular `std::streambuf` implementation.

Comment: +1.  sputn and xsputn are often implemented in terms of sputc unless they can implement it more efficiently.

Comment: aha. Would implementing overflow, underflow, sync and xsputn/xsgetn be sufficient then?

Comment: @stijn: Yes, and you don't need to implement `xsputn` and `xsgetn`. Once you've got a working implementation of `overflow`, you may find that you don't gain any advantage with a custom `xsputn`. You don't need to overload `uflow` because the default implementation is implemented using `underflow` anyway.